# How to keep value in Spinner when scrolling ListView with Spinner in it?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am facing this problem and have read lots of questions/answers but could not solve it.

I have a ListView with Spinner (user must choose a quantity number for the product in that row), but when there are items more than the view and the ListView is scrolled after selecting a number in the spinner this number disappears and the default is shown again.

I have an adapter to the Spinner being created inside the adapter for ListView itself:

```
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.layout_spinner_quanitdade, quantities) {

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView) v).setTextSize(18);
        return v;
    }

    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.END);
        return v;
    }
};

holder.spinnerQuantidade.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
holder.spinnerQuantidade.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int spinnerPosition, long id) {

        String newQuantity = quantities[spinnerPosition];
        item.setQuantidade(newQuantity);

        Spinner theSpinner = (Spinner) parent;
        theSpinner.setSelection(spinnerPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Before trying to select a value in the Spinner (look at the row with the word IMEI):
[image]

After choosing a value in the spinner for the row:
[image]

After scrolling up and then scrolling down (value changes back to 1, instead of the 10 I choose):
[image]

UPDATE: changed to try to keep and set the spinner selection, did not work:

```
    public View getView(final int modelPosition, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    final Produto item = getItem(modelPosition);

    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (view == null) {
        view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_produto, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textViewCodigo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewCodigo);
        holder.textViewNome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewNome);
        holder.spinnerQuantidade = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerQuantidade);
        holder.spinnerQuantidade.setTag(modelPosition);

        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        holder.checkBox = chk;
        holder.checkBox.setTag(modelPosition);

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    if (modelPosition % 2 == 0) {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cor_zebra2);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cor_zebra1);
    }

    holder.textViewCodigo.setText(item.getCodigo());
    holder.textViewNome.setText(item.getDescricao().trim());

// checking and settion spinner selection - DID NOT WORK
    if (mapRowSpinnerPos.containsKey(modelPosition)) {
        holder.spinnerQuantidade.setSelection(mapRowSpinnerPos.get(modelPosition));
    }

    if (this.showChecks) {
        holder.spinnerQuantidade.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isChecked());
        holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                item.setChecked(isChecked);
                if (isChecked) {
                    selectedList.add(item);
                } else {
                    selectedList.remove(item);
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        // situation 2: show spinners
        holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.layout_spinner_quanitdade, quantities) {

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                ((TextView) v).setTextSize(18);
                return v;
            }

            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                ((TextView) v).setGravity(Gravity.END);
                return v;
            }
        };

        holder.spinnerQuantidade.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        holder.spinnerQuantidade.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int spinnerPosition, long id) {

                // int thePosition = (Integer) parent.getTag();
                mapRowSpinnerPos.put(modelPosition, spinnerPosition);

                String newQuantity = quantities[spinnerPosition];
                item.setQuantidade(newQuantity);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move the below code after you set the adapter. Setting the adapter would set it to first position.

```
if (mapRowSpinnerPos.containsKey(modelPosition)) {
    holder.spinnerQuantidade.setSelection(mapRowSpinnerPos.get(modelPosition));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` reuses its views, so only those currently showing are populated.
So when a list item reenteres the screen, it get repopulated.

To keep each spinner's state, your adapter should have a field to keep each item's selected value, which would be updated from the spinner selection, and then, on the getView method, you will check that selection from the adapter and set the spinner to the selected item.

Comment: See my update, I did what you said, and didn't work at all